# React.lazy import { StudentDashaboard, StudentLearningView } from './studentView.jsx';

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

What is the correct syntax for importing multiple items from one file with React.lazy?

For example

```
import { ClassOne, ClassTwo } from './components.jsx';
```

Comment: const ClassOne = React.lazy(() => import('./components.jsx').then(module => ({ default: module.ClassOne }))); didn't work, but might be close.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined is what I get with this and with trying react-lazily which from what I understand is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had  higher up in the code, but apparently that wasn't sufficient.

I had to add it closer to my component which was on a route:

```
<Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
        <Router>
        <div className='children'>
            <Route path="/demo/:product" component={Demo} />
```